# Zod Union Schema supporting alternate possibilities

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm using VS Code with validation for a [Zod](https://zod.dev/?id=unions) schema for result of an API call which will *either* return:

```json
{
  "Appointment":
    {
      "Name": "etc..."
    }
}
```

Or it will return a similarly shaped `Error` object.

However, in the codebase that parses the result, VS Code warns of an error on *either* the `.Appointment` or the `.Error` attribute, citing that it may not exist.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```js
import z from 'zod';
import { useState } from "react";

const appointmentSchema = z
  .object({
    Appointment: z.string(),
  })
  .or(
    z.object({
      Error: z.object({
        Message: z.string(),
      }),
    }),
);

type AppointmentSchema = z.infer<typeof appointmentSchema>;

const twoObjects = [
  {
    Appointment: "test"
  },
  {
    Error: {
    Message: "test",
    }
  },
];

const random = async ():Promise<AppointmentSchema> => {
  const rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * twoObjects.length);
  return twoObjects[rando];
}

export default function View() {

  const [appointment, setAppointment] = useState<AppointmentSchema>();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Testing!!!!</h1>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          const randObject = await random();
          setAppointment(randObject);
        }
      }>Random Select</button>
      {appointment && appointment.Appointment && <div>Appointment: {appointment.Appointment}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this an error on the editor's part, or am I using Zod (or TypeScript) incorrectly?

#### UPDATE:

Thanks to the link to the TypeScript [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) doc reference in the comment, I am able to narrow manually like this:

```
{appointment && typeof appointment === 'object' && 'Appointment' in appointment && (
  <div>Appointment: {appointment.Appointment}</div>
)}
```

I can even utilize a zod object:

```
const appointmentOnlySchema = z.object({
  Appointment: z.string(),
});
type AppointmentOnlySchema = z.infer<typeof appointmentOnlySchema>;
```

And replace `'object'` with `typeof appointmentOnlySchema` (or even `appointmentOnlySchema.safeParse(appointment).success`), but the editor is still complaining that the object might not contain the specified attribute.

Found a [blog post](https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/type-safe-typescript-with-type-narrowing) that might help. Input still very welcome.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - are you checking which you get _before_ assuming which properties it will have?

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated post with usage example. I'm not sure what you mean by "checking... _before_ assuming". Is there a way of querying with Zod before casting the type, or dynamically casting _after_ a request has been completed?

Comment: That's still not runnable. Presumably `AppointmentResponseSchema` is something like `{ Appointment: ... } | { Error: ... }`, so you need to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it before you can access properties that only exist in a subset of the union. E.g. `'Error' in apptUpdateStatus ? ... : ...`.

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe. Thanks for your patience and for the link to "narrow" docs. Added an updated example. Is the idea, then, to have a Schema for _each_ of the possible types (Error and Appointment-containing in this case)?

Comment: Zod is basically irrelevant here (as is React), and everything is working correctly. Actual MRE would be something like: https://tsplay.dev/w8gJMW. You don't know, on the line where you're rendering the button text, which half of `{ Appointment: ... } | { Error: ... }` you have. So you need to discriminate the union, as the docs show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the commentary above is correct that the issue isn't relevant to zod (*nor* React).

Also seems that checking if `items === 'object'` is unnecessary.

Can just check for presence of item attribute:

```
type AppointmentSchema = { Appointment: string } | { Error: { message: string } };

function thing(appointment: AppointmentSchema): string {
  if ('Appointment' in appointment)
    return appointment && appointment.Appointment;
  return "error";
}
```